# SPSS Form questions weight

Tags: linear-regression, spss, pca, survey, weighted

I have an issue with SPSS.
I have a survey with about 20 questions, and about 40 people who answered it.

I want to explain my 2nd question of the survey with the result of others.

In fact, i want to extract the weight of each question regarding the 2nd question.

For example, the answer 1 weights 5% of question 2 result, the answer 3 weights 8% of question 2 result, ...

I don't find how to do it.

Maybe first i need to clean my data with PCA or multiple linear regression ?

If anybody got an idea it would be amazing.

Ps: Sorry for my bad english if something's not clear tell me i will try to explain my point better.

Thanks in advance and have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

So what you are trying to do, is to find the influences of answers on other question on the answer of question two? 
You should do some sort of regression analysis. 
Fill in your depending variable (question 2 and your independent answers question 1 and 3.

This will show what the influence of the other answers is on question 2.